# Vertical Layout + Content Size Fitter

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface

I have a panel where the buttons are added dynamically and with that combination my panel resizes automatically, my question... is it possible for the resize to just go down and not grow to the top and to the bot?

The first image is the grow up in both directions.
The second image is a example of where I want to go:

[image: First]  [image: Second]

I try with all the Layout component

Comment: are you sure its growing both ends and not just seeming to because you told it to be centered?

Answer (score 0):

Just adjust your pivot settings accordingly.

In order to make a panel (actually any `RectTransform`) to only grow in the down direction you just need to have set

Pivot: `y` = `0.5 (center)` → `1 (top edge)`

Now if the `height` is changed by the `ContentSizeFitter` it will only grow top-down

[image]

Alternatively you can also do the same directly via the layout/anchoring widget.

- By holding down <kbd>ALT</kbd> you make your panel snap to the edges (resetting all offsets)
- By holding down <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> you also tell it to apply the pivot to the edge/center accordingly

So in your case you probably want to hold down combined <kbd>ALT + SHIFT</kbd> and then use the streched-top layout

[image]